# Verify a submitted form without the PHP redirection to the action page

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I'd like to submit a form thanks to AJAX and display the error messages contained in "form_treatment.php" (form verification) without the php redirection to "form_treatment.php" when I submit. What have I to write in the following lign ?

```
$.post("form_treatment.php",name, ???);
```

I have a basic form in form.php :

```
<form method="post" action="form_treatment.php" >
    <input type="text" name="user_name" value="Your name..." /> 
    <button type="submit" >OK</button>
</form>
```

This form is treat in form_treatment.php :

```
if ( empty($_POST['user_name']) ){      
    echo 'You have to enter your name.';        
} else { 
    $already_existing = verify_existence( $_POST['user_name'] ); 
    // verification in the DB, return true or false

    if( $already_existing ){
        echo 'Name already used.';
    } else {    
        // Entering the name in the DB
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like the following:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="form_treatment.php" >
    <span id="message"></span>
    <input type="text" name="user_name" value="Your name..." /> 
    <input type="submit" >OK</button>
</form>
```

And the javascript:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
  var myForm = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'form_treatment.php',
    data: myForm.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
       $('#message').html(data);
    }
  }); 
  return false;
});
```

Comment: When I submit It displays the whole page html (with the header, the footer...) in  <span id="message"></span>. What's the problem ?

Comment: Make sure that the PHP script, that handles the post submit, generates only the text you want to be displayed in the span without the header and footer.

Comment: In fact It was because I use MVC so it generates me all the html page code. But tell me, how can I get (still in my ajax script) a var returned by "form_treatment.php" ? I want to close the colorbox (a lightbox) containing my form only if "form_treatment.php" returns a string like "Verification is OK" =)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by two ways 
1st One in the same page 
2nd one via AJAX 
**The first way can be done like this**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sub']) && $_POST['sub'] == 'true'):
if ( empty($_POST['user_name']) ){      
    echo 'You have to enter your name.';        
} else { 
    $already_existing = verify_existence( $_POST['user_name'] ); 
    // verification in the DB, return true or false

    if( $already_existing ){
        echo 'Name already used.';
    } else {    
        // Entering the name in the DB
    }
}

endif; 
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" >
    <input type="text" name="user_name" value="Your name..." /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="sub" value = "true" >
    <button type="submit" >OK</button>
</form>
```

**The 2nd way via ajax** 
can be done like this

```
<div id="errors"></div>
<form method="post" id="myFrm">
        <input type="text" name="user_name" value="Your name..." id="name" /> 
        <button type="submit" >OK</button>
</form> 

<sctipt>
$("#myFrm").submit(function() {
  var NameFromForm = $('#name').val(); 
   $.post("form_treatment.php", { "user_name": NameFromForm },
 function(data){
   $("#errors").html(data); 
 });
    event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

If you need any explanation leave a comment

Comment: Hi, your code functions but when I submit It displays the whole page html (with the header, the footer...) in  <span id="message"></span>. What's the problem ?